# paging through cql query on django

Tags: django, cassandra, cassandra-driver

I have two queries. One that gives me the first page from a cassandra table, and another one that retrieves the successive pages. The fist one is like :

```
select * from images_by_user where token(iduser) = token(5) limit 10 allow filtering;
```

The successive ones are :

```
select * from images_by_user where token(iduser) = token(5) and imagekey > 90b18881-ccd3-4ed4-8cdf-d71eb99b3505 limit 10 allow filtering;
```

where the image key is the last one on the first page.

I have 13 rows in the table. The first query returns 10 both on the cqlsh and the application (consistency level ONE just for development).
The second query only retrieves results on clash. Below is the cassandra database engine configuration I have on the django application :

```
'ENGINE': 'django_cassandra_engine',
'NAME': 'xekmypic',
'HOST': 'localhost',
'OPTIONS': {
    'replication': {
        'strategy_class': 'SimpleStrategy',
        'replication_factor': 1
    },
    'connection': {
        'consistency': ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE,
        'retry_connect': True
        # + All connection options for cassandra.cluster.Cluster()
    }
}
```

The cassandra version I am using is doc-3.0.9 and below is my virtual env pip list :

```
cassandra-driver (3.9.0)
Cython (0.25)
Django (1.11)
django-cassandra-engine (1.1.0)
mysqlclient (1.3.10)
olefile (0.44)
Pillow (4.1.0)
pip (7.1.2)
python-memcached (1.58)
pytz (2017.2)
setuptools (18.2)
six (1.10.0)
```

Why does the second page does not return any results on the application but does on cqlsh prompt ?

Comment: Please provide table structure and full table data. 
make sure that all 13 rows falls under the same userID (5).

Comment: table structure : create table images_by_user (
  iduser    bigint
 ,imagekey   uuid
 ,PRIMARY KEY ((iduser), imagekey)
);